# Docker-compose error in Jenkins "docker-compose: No such file or directory"

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am making a CI/CD pipeline for an application with React Js front-end and Java Spring Boot backend. When I run the build every time fail and get an error. I face this error with both Jenkins running on the server and running on my local machine.

```
Error Jenkins running on local :+ /usr/bin/docker-compose up --build -d
/var/root/.jenkins/workspace/flight-test-pipeline@tmp/durable-3512619f/script.sh: line 1: /usr/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory


Error Jenkins running on server:  + docker-compose build
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Build-pipeline@tmp/durable-94a5213e/script.sh: 1: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Build-pipeline@tmp/durable-94a5213e/script.sh: docker-compose: not found
```

Jenkins script is here:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
        PATH = "$PATH:/usr/local/bin/docker-compose"
    }
    agent any
  stages {  
    stage('Start container') {
      steps {
        sh "/usr/bin/docker-compose up --build -d"
      }
    }
    
    stage('Build') {

      steps {

        sh 'Docker build -t registry.has.de/jenk1:v1 .'

      }

    }
    stage('Login') {

      steps {

        sh 'echo docker login registry.has.de --username=furqan.iqbal --password=123...

      }

    }

    stage('Push to Has registry') {

      steps {

        sh '''
          Docker push registry.has.de/jenk1:v1
        '''

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Did you install docker-compose on your jenkins server? Moreover, since you are using an absolute path, did you check the command exists in the precise path you configured in your job? Your error message is quite clear: the command does not exists (at least in that very specific location...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i recall correctly, Jenkins can't understand what '$PATH' is, so you need to do the following:

```
environment {
        p = sh 'echo $PATH'
        PATH = p + ':/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'
    }
```

Comment: WorkflowScript: 4: Environment variable values to be concatenated together must be single or double quoted. @ line 4, column 16.
           PATH = p + ':/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'